# Java: Prevent override of a member variable

Tags: java, oop

A useful feature in Java is the option to declare a member method as final, so that it cannot be overridden in descendant classes. Is there something similar for member variables?

```
class Parent {
  public final void thisMethodMustRemainAsItIs() { /* ... */ }
  public String thisVariableMustNotBeHidden;
}

class Child extends Parent {
  public final void thisMethodMustRemainAsItIs() { /* ... */ }  // Causes an error
  public String thisVariableMustNotBeHidden;  // Causes no error!
}
```

EDIT: sorry, I should elaborate more on the scenario: I have a variable in the parent class, that should be updated by child classes (therefore it must not be private). However, if a child class creates a variable with the same name, it will THINK that it has updated the parent variable, even though it updated its own copy:

```
class Parent {
    protected String myDatabase = null; // Should be updated by children
    public void doSomethingWithMyDatabase() { /* ... */ }
}

class GoodChild extends Parent {
    public GoodChild() {  
      myDatabase = "123"; 
      doSomethingWithMyDatabase();
    }
}

class BadChild extends Parent {
    protected String myDatabase = null; // Hides the parent variable!
    public BadChild() {  
      myDatabase = "123";  // Updates the child and not the parent!
      doSomethingWithMyDatabase(); // NullPointerException
    }
}
```

This is what I want to prevent.

Comment: Making them private with final accessors won't do the job?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

declare your variable private, and use getter .

Comment: It's better to declare the variable private anyway, to preserve encapsulation. Or protected when you want to allow subclasses to access it, which is not your case here. But not public, never.

Comment: Even in the protected case I recommend to use private variables and protected accessors.

Comment: I need to update this variable in the child classes - see my edit.

Answer (score 4):

keep it `private`

Comment: I need to update this variable in the child classes - see my edit.